# Syntax to not write single statement to binlog?

Tags: mysql, replication

I know you can `SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;` to disable writing your session to the binlogs.

I was wondering if there was some single serving query syntax to prevent just that one query from being written w/o setting that session var to 0 and back to 1 afterwards?

Comment: Sounds dangerous; messing up data consistency on your slaves. I'm curious why you would want to do this

Comment: Just some financial data. J/k It's basically heart beat updates from applications every couple of seconds.  If there was a disaster and we had to restore or fail over we wouldn't care if had to start from scratch.  It's not really causing a problem other than annoying me when looking through binlogs and got me curious :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do the following:

- connect to mysql
- perform `SET sql_log_bin=0;`
- execute the query (INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE)
- close the DB connection

then there is no need to `SET sql_log_bin=1;` afterwards

As an alternative, you may want to try this:

- open a second DB Connection
- set the `SET sql_log_bin=0;` (this done once in the lifetime of the second DB connection)
- keep that second DB Connection open
- use only this second DB connection for writes that are not be recorded in the binary logs

Give it a Try !!!

### **UPDATE 2012-01-06 14:55 EDT**

Here is something interesting you may not have realized: [Only those SUPER privilege can set one's own session to disable binary logging](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_log_bin).

According to the [MySQL Documentation on SUPER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super):

> The SUPER privilege enables an account to use CHANGE MASTER TO, KILL
> or mysqladmin kill to kill threads belonging to other accounts (you
> can always kill your own threads), PURGE BINARY LOGS, configuration
> changes using SET GLOBAL to modify global system variables, the
> mysqladmin debug command, enabling or disabling logging, performing
> updates even if the read_only system variable is enabled, starting and
> stopping replication on slave servers, specification of any account in
> the DEFINER attribute of stored programs and views, and enables you to
> connect (once) even if the connection limit controlled by the
> max_connections system variable is reached.
>
> To create or alter stored functions if binary logging is enabled, you
> may also need the SUPER privilege, as described in Section 18.7,
> “Binary Logging of Stored Programs”.

Having users with SUPER privilege gives them additional fire power that they may not need or may want to abuse.

Comment: The context for this was hoping I could pass something simple along to our developers along the lines "insert ignore..." w/o them having to worry about managing the separate connections just for this purpose.  Also these are persistent Java apps that keep connections open.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I've run into something similar.  You don't want to grant `SUPER`, that's for sure...

I know developers are not always keen on Stored Procedures, but this might be a case for them.  Here's an example procedure to update a "heartbeat" table which you may not want replicated among your slaves.

```
set @app_nm='Unicorns and Rainbows';

create table hb_status(heartbeat datetime, app_nm varchar(60));

DELIMITER $$

create 
definer = 'root'@'localhost'
procedure hb_update_no_log (p_app_nm varchar(60))
begin

set sql_log_bin = 0;

update hb_status
set heartbeat=now()
where app_nm = 'Unicorns and Rainbows';

set sql_log_bin = 1;

end $$

DELIMITER ;

insert into hb_status values(now(), @app_nm);
select * from hb_status; 
select sleep(1);
call hb_update_no_log(@app_nm);
select * from hb_status;
```

Notes:
- `definer` clause is used to change the security context to a user with `SUPER` privilege.
- I have not done extensive testing on this yet.
- I do something similar to this (use of `definer`) to allow developers to grant/revoke privileges in break/fix situations.